# How to have different style files in multilingual website using Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6, multilingual, drupal-theming

I have been developing a multilingual website using Drupal 6. The languages are English and Spanish. I want to have some different backgrounds and css for them. But both use just style.css.

How can I create different style.css file for them? For example style-sp.css for Spanish one and en-style.css for English one ?

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

append to template.php in your theme this code:

```
global $language;
drupal_add_css(path_to_theme().'/style-'.$language->language.'.css','file');
```